# How to detect a sknode hovers over another?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game where I drag pieces over containers and if they match it can be placed if not, then returns to the bin, How can I detect if a sknode is hovering over the container, or how can I compare the 2 sprites? Thank you! any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

To see if they are hovering over one another, you could use the `intersects` function of `CGRect` using each nodes `frame` property (which is a CGRect). If the frames intersect, then they are overlapping to some extent.

To identify if the nodes are the same shape, then I’d restrict yourself to a specific range of shapes and have the nodes `name` property reflect what shape it is.

Edit: You could of course also use Sprite-kit's contact detection. Set it up correctly and you;ll only get notified when the correct shapes are placed over the correct containers.

Comment: SKNode has its own intersect function

Comment: Frame intersect is not a good way to check,  if 2 nodes are on 2 different branches, their frames could cause a false intersection because the values in frame is relative to the parent